# Persistent (hardware?) problems over multiple Ubuntu reinstallations

Tags: hardware

I recently reinstalled `Ubuntu 14.04.2` multiple times, after having experienced a persistent problem with `Oracle Java 8`, which suddenly started crashing in any application in which used to work. Namely the problem was always a "problematic frame" in a static library (`.so file`), with lots of hexadecimal addresses listed above in the log. Reinstalling `Java` didn't help, so I tried reinstalling `Ubuntu` instead, but the problem persisted even after a fresh installation.

I then checked RAMs for faulty behavior, and soon after having started `Memtest86+ v4.2.0` lots of addresses were reported as faulty. I checked if everything in the BIOS was set correctly, and i found out that the memory's `Command Rate` was set uncorrectly to `1`, while from RAM's specifications it should have been set to `2`. So i set it to `2` and tested again, this time with 1 full pass of `Memtest86+` and 3 full pass of `Memtest86` showing no issue.

In order to avoid any further problems i burned `Ubuntu` again to a blank DVD, checked the md5 sum of the DVD, launched `Ubuntu` as Live DVD and checked the `S.M.A.R.T` status of the drive, which was ok (`Bad sectors reallocation count=0`). The problem i'm experiencing now is that the installer fails at checking copied files, i.e. it states that the copied files are different from the source files.

Now i'm trying to burn the `Ubuntu` DVD once again, but i highly doubt it might fix the issue. Apparently there's something wrong at hardware level, but i'm unable to figure out what that could be

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it was RAMs' fault. After having opened the case, having removed the RAMs and removed lots of dust from their heatsinks, having cleaned everything else from the lots of dust present and having updated the BIOS to a new version which sets the memory timings correctly i was able to reinstall and to use the PC without problems